# Dokku fails due to bundler version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dokku

I had a Ruby on Rails app up and running with Dokku. When I tried to deploy it again today, I received the following error:

```sh
--> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.0.1
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Activating bundler (2.0.2) failed:
       Could not find 'bundler' (2.0.2) required by your /tmp/build/Gemfile.lock.
       To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
       To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.0.2`
       Checked in 'GEM_PATH=vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0', execute `gem env` for more information

       To install the version of bundler this project requires, run `gem install bundler -v '2.0.2'`
       Bundler Output: Activating bundler (2.0.2) failed:
       Could not find 'bundler' (2.0.2) required by your /tmp/build/Gemfile.lock.
       To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
       To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.0.2`
       Checked in 'GEM_PATH=vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0', execute `gem env` for more information

       To install the version of bundler this project requires, run `gem install bundler -v '2.0.2'`

       !
       !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
```

Not sure how to resolve this and was unable to find any references to this type of problem with Dokku.

Comment: I think I've seen this before. As I remember first thing I tried was to make sure Bundler versions are in sync. Meaning, in Gemfile.lock you have "2.0.2", but then on Dokku side it shows you "2.0.1". It might be some [caching thing probably](https://github.com/dokku/dokku/blob/master/docs/advanced-usage/repository-management.md) As I remember I ended up downgrading Bundler to v1.

Answer (score 4):

The update didn't change the Bundler version for me.

I solved this by [changing the buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version#using-an-older-version-of-bundler). Syntax for dokku is:

```sh
$ dokku config:set --no-restart YOUR_APP BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git#v227
```

`#227` gives Bundler 2.2.16 which works with my installed version 2.2.20.

Here is a [list of available buildpacks](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md).

Comment: Great answer.  Just in time, too :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by updating Dokku using their official documentation. After the update, I had no trouble deploying.

Comment: This solved it for me too. I basically did a full apt update and upgrade.